# Tunnelling IP Multicast traffic between two residential networks or machines

Tags: networking, iproute, udp, tunneling, multicast

The Ableton Link music synchronization service operates by broadcasting and receiving messages via an IPv4 multicast group in the "Ad-Hoc 2" address block.

In order to use the protocol to synchronize music across LAN boundaries, we would like to connect two Linux machines running the Ableton Link software in their own residential LAN networks via the Internet. A centralized server (also running Linux) is available for tunneling traffic and traversing firewalls.

- Which tools and protocols are best suited to this task? (IPSec, OpenVPN, BER...?)
- How would one set this up on a common Linux installation using iproute2?